# Sampling a 2D Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, ising-model, lattice-model

I am fairly new to statistical mechanics and I am coming from a computing background. I am trying to calculate the mutual information of a lattice representing the 2D ferromagnetic Ising Model using machine learning. But I am having a hard time understanding how to generate samples from the Ising Model. I am working with this description: "spin models were simulated for a system of 64 x 64 spins with periodic boundary conditions. The distribution was sampled using standard, well-established methods: The Ising models were simulated using Metropolis Monte Carlo simulations." Based on this quote, I need to generate 5000 samples but I am not sure how that is done. Do we run the Metropolis algorithm on the same lattice 5000 times with the same temperature? Or do we generate 5000 random lattices and run the Metropolis algorithm once on each of them (all with the same temperature)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the Computational Science site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the Metropolis Algorithm already contains the number of samples you want to get. However, I appreciate this may not how it's understood for different fields. What you (probably) want to do may be summarised as follows:

- Pick a temperature T
- Pick a random lattice spin configuration $\{s_i\}$ and calculate the associated energy $E[\{s_i\}]$
- Choose random sites (the number should be chosen accordingly) and flip their spins.
- Calculate the new energy associated with this configuration $E'[\{s_i\}]$
- Accept this new configuration with probability $p = max(1, e^{ -\Delta E/T})$
- Repeat until you have sampled enough configurations.

This process will give you a set of spin configurations that follow the Boltzmann distribution $e^{-\beta E[\{s_i\}]}$.

One further thing to note is that because of this algorithm the consecutive configurations will be correlated to an extent. This will bias your sampled distribution and you will get awkward results. To do this, you need to pick your accepted configurations with some step size. To read more about this, you can look at the following paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378437121005045?via%3Dihub

Comment: Thank you for your answer.